# Sprinkler Zone Drops in Pressure

Tags: water-pressure, irrigation

I have a situation I've never seen previously.  I have a zone of sprayheads (popups) that should have sufficient pressure, based on testing of the system GPM (15gpm) and the requirements of the six sprayheads on the zone (8.5gpm).  It is fed by a shallow well pump and all other zones work fine, both sprayheads and rotors.  But this one zone starts off great, popping up and spraying with utter abandon, but after about 10 minutes they sink down and dribble like they don't have sufficient pressure.  The system is not connected to any other inflow or outflows, just the irrigation zones.  No other zone appears to be inappropriately coming on during this time. If I wait awhile and start them again, the same thing happens. The pump runs at about 24psi initially, but when it begins having the problem it drops to low pressure, about 5-8psi.
I thought of the idea that this might be a result of lack of water in the well and after a while the water was filling into the well, but discounted this when I saw that other zones work fine if I turn them on immediately after this zone starts having its problem, so this doesn't appear to be the cause.  I'm frankly stumped!

Comment: where are you measuring the pump pressure?

Comment: I'd check for a broken pipe someplace. Any flooding in certain areas in that zone? You probably have a pressure tank (being on a well system), with a certain supply rate, once the pressurized supply of the tank is exhausted and the pump can't keep up with demand , you'll see a dramatic drop in water pressure. Again, probably a broken pipe in that zone.